# lookup into another dataframe and filter value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe named *df*  which has two columns id1 and id2

I need to filter values based on some other df named as *meta_df*

meta_df has three columns id,name,text

df

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 |
| 99 | 42 |

metadf

| id | name | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | aa | lowerend |
| 42 | bb | upperend |
| 99 | cc | upper limit |
| 34 | dd | uppersome |

I need values from text  which have lower and upper in string of text. e.g 12 and 34
I am trying the below code and stuck at getting text clumn

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.Index, row.id1, row.id2)
    print(meta_df[id['id']== row.id1])
    print(meta_df[id['id']== row.id2])
```

Output Expected

| id2 | id2 | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | yes |
| 99 | 42 | no |

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: thanks for the response..sure I will update

Comment: @sammywemmy done .pls check

Comment: flag or any column that separate both id..just to identify..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melt `df` and merge to `metadf`, a bit of reshaping before getting the final value:

```py
            # keep the index with ignore_index
            # it will be used when reshaping back to original form
reshaped = (df.melt(value_name = 'id', ignore_index = False)
              .assign(ind=lambda df: df.index)
              .merge(metadf, on='id', how = 'left')
              .assign(text = lambda df: df.text.str.contains('lower'))
              .drop(columns='name')
              .pivot('ind', 'variable')
              .rename_axis(columns=[None, None], index=None)
)

# if the row contains both lower(1) and upper(0)
# it will sum to 1, else 0, or 2(unlikely with the sample data shared)
flag = reshaped.loc(axis=1)['text'].sum(1)

reshaped.loc(axis=1)['id'].assign(flag = flag.map({1:'yes', 0:'no'}))

   id1  id2 flag
0   12   34  yes
1   99   42   no
```

Comment: thanks..  so the text filter check if one id has 'lower'..? I am not able to understand how the flag is being assigned..

Comment: I added some comments to the code explaining it. Let me know if you want more details